# Как сделать выборку из json по первой букве в значении элемента

Tags: jquery, json

Как можно выполнить поиск элемента в json по первой букве в его значении? Мой код почему-то не работает.

```
{"airlines":[{"iata":"NM","name":"Mount Cook Airlines"}]}
```

Код:

```
var airlines;

$.getJSON('/json/airlines.json', function(json){
    airlines = json;
});

for (var i = 0; i < airlines.length; i++) {
        if ((airlines[i].name).slice(0,1) == 'M') {
            //do smth
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вы ведь не забыли распарсить json в объект?

Comment: @br3t ну конечно же. Обновил код.

Comment: Вроде getJSON не передает наружу переменные, надо внутри него поставить цикл.

Comment: @greybutton всё он прекрасно передаёт. Пользуюсь аналогичным способом на одной странице.

Comment: Наверное, у вас в переменной `airlines` находится не то, что вы ожидаете. Попробуйте `airlines = json.airlines;`

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin Хм. Вы ведь помните, что `getJSON` - асинхронная функция и ваш `for` выполнится до того, как в `airlines` что-то попадет?

Comment: @br3t да, это я знаю. В моём скрипте for выполняется по клику на кнопку.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(airlines, function(key, value){
    if (key == 'M') {
        //do smth
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. В цикле нужно использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
for (var i in airlines.airlines) {
```

Comment: Обычный for по `airlines.airlines` тоже должен сработать.

Answer (score 0):

Вы вкурсе что $.getJSON - это асинхронная операция?

Если запустить следующий код,

```
console.log('BEFORE');
$.getJSON('/json/airlines.json', function(json){
    console.log(json);
});
console.log('AFTER');
```

вы получите в консоли что-то типа такого:

- BEFORE
- AFTER
- {...}

Советую вам изучить async/await и использовать функцию fetch=)